# Handling multiple tabs during landscape and portrait in android

Tags: android, layout, tabs, orientation, landscape-portrait

I have specified different layouts for landscape and portrait using layout and layout-land, my application have multiple tabs. Each time when changing from portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait screen changes to 1st tab even selected tab is different one. How can we solve this problem.

Comment: If you override the on orientation changed method, you can set the active tab. Not sure if this is really a good fix, so just a comment. Assuming you use horisontal and vertical layouts and default method

Comment: You may keep the order of active tab in a static variable. Then after initializing all your layout stuff, inflating your tab control also. You may get this static data value and set active tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to solve this issue.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ....
   lastTab = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
   .....
   if(lastTab != null)
   {
      tabs.setCurrentTab(lastTab);
   }
}

public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() 
{
   return tabs.getCurrentTab();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rotating the device will, by default, destroy and recreate your Activity. You need to save the state of your selected tab, and restore it when the new Activity is launched.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // onCreate implementation goes here

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        int selectedTabIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("selectedTabIndex");
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(selectedTabIndex);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("selectedTabIndex", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}
```

Comment: Tried this. I got an exception.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo()
java.lang.IllegalStateException: setSelectedNavigationIndex not valid for current navigation mode

Comment: Are you using tabs on the Action Bar? You would obviously replace that with whatever you are using for tabs.

Answer (score 0):

when you change the orientation it will reload the Activity. That is why its giving 1 st tab.Use in your manifest file
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
if it will not work fine then go for 
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}